# Vite reloading full page on every change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

On the newer version of vite, it was causing full page reload even on all the changes, wheather i change a text or remove a heading tag. Adding **import.meta.hot.accept()** in my index.js file fixed the issue but it caused the build to fail **causing the error:**

```
index-f28df0af.js:1195  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'accept')
    at index-f28df0af.js:1195:82439
    at index-f28df0af.js:1:23
    at index-f28df0af.js:1195:82709
```

On every change the vite compiler says **Full page reload**, instead of doing a **HMR update**. On previous version of vite 3.0.*, i was not getting full page reload and HMR update was working fine, after updating to the latest version I started encountering this full page reload, making the development experience slow and worse.

> package.json file

```
    {
    "name": "Lala-Intl",
    "homepage": "http://lalaintltravel.pk/",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.0",
        "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.2.0",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.0",
        "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
        "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.3",
        "@mui/x-date-pickers-pro": "^6.6.0",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.4",
        "antd": "^5.8.1",
        "axios": "^0.27.2",
        "jquery": "^3.6.1",
        "mdb-react-ui-kit": "^6.1.0",
        "moment": "^2.29.4",
        "pickadate": "^3.6.4",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-bootstrap": "^2.5.0",
        "react-date-range": "^1.4.0",
        "react-datepicker": "^4.12.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
        "react-multi-carousel": "^2.8.2",
        "react-redux": "^8.1.2",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.13.0",
        "react-select": "^5.7.4",
        "react-spinners": "^0.13.8",
        "redux": "^4.2.1",
        "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
        "usehooks-ts": "^2.7.0",
        "vite": "^4.4.8",
        "vite-plugin-svgr": "^3.2.0",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build",
        "serve": "vite preview"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
           ]
        }
    }
```

> Index.js

```
    import React from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
    import { Provider } from "react-redux";
    import { store, persistor } from "./store";
    import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
    import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

    // meta.hot.accept is required for HMR update
    // import.meta.hot.accept();

    import "./index.css";
    import App from "./App";

    ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
                <React.StrictMode>
                    <React.StrictMode>
                        <BrowserRouter basename="/">
                            <App />
                        </BrowserRouter>
                    </React.StrictMode>
                </React.StrictMode>
            </PersistGate>
        </Provider>
     );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following condition in your index.js file.

```
if (import.meta.hot) {
    import.meta.hot.accept();
}
```